# SpreadsheetMLPackage.load from docx4j in Java return an OOXML file, not an XLSX file

Tags: java, excel, openxml, xlsx, docx4j

I'm opening an XLSX file like this:

```
File file = new File("myPath/to/file.xlsx");
SpreadsheetMLPackage pkg = SpreadsheetMLPackage.load(file);
```

Then, without doing anything, I save it in the same file:

```
pkg.save(file);
```

**My file is now a Microsoft OOXML file, not a Microsoft Excel 2007+ file** as it was before.

How can I get a Microsoft Excel 2007+ file?

### Note

If I create a new file like this:

```
SpreadsheetMLPackage pkg = SpreadsheetMLPackage.createPackage();
pkg.save(file);
```

My output is a Microsoft Excel 2007+ file. So it seems strange that loading the file convert it into OOXML format.

### Steps to reproduce

1. Create an Excel file (for me, on windows with Excel 2013) and save it as `test.xlsx`.
2. Pass this file to Ubuntu. Run this command: `file test.xlsx`, you get 
   `test.xlsx: Microsoft Excel 2007+`.
3. Execute this script:

   ```
   try {
       File file = new File("/home/userName/Downloads/test.xlsx");
       SpreadsheetMLPackage pkg = SpreadsheetMLPackage.load(file);
       pkg.save(file);
   } catch (Docx4JException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
   ```
4. Run again this command: `file test.xlsx` and this time you get 
   `test.xlsx: Microsoft OOXML`.

Comment: When you say "My file is now a Microsoft OOXML file", what do you mean exactly, and what leads you to this conclusion?

Comment: I've added steps to reproduce. I hope it'll help you to understand my issue.

Comment: Probably just a quirk in how the files program sniffs files.  If I get a chance, I'll take a look later.

Comment: yes probably. It seems that there is no difference for Excel, everything is working well so...